# Is it possible to pass non-model data to render helper?

Tags: ember.js

I'm using `render` helper to create widgets that fetch their own data by defining `content` method in their controller:

```
{{render "popular_posts"}}

App.PopularPostsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    content: function () {
        return this.store.find('post', { order_by: 'views', per: 5 };
    }.property()
})
```

This works fine, but posts can be tagged and when I'm on a page for specific tag, I'd like to reuse the same widget, but I need to pass a tag to it to display popular posts only with a specific tag.

Currently I'm getting the tag from the parent controller and if it exists, I'm adding it to the request query params. However, rendering it like this (without passing model object) causes `PopularPostsController` to be a singleton, so it displays the same data on every page.

I can change it to be non-singleton like this:

```
App.register(
    'controller:popular_posts',
    App.PopularPostsController,
    {singleton: false}
);
```

and it works, but it would be great to be able to pass data to `render` helper other than model (`tag` in my case). Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Render takes a second parameter which is the model you want the render controller to use.  There's nothing special about the "model" you pass to Render and you can pass just about anything (e.g., an object, an array of objects, etc.)

So you should be able to do:

```
{{render "popularPosts" tags}}
```

This will use the `popular_posts` template and instantiate a `PopularPostsController` with the model set to your array of tags.  You could then access the `tags` in your popular_posts template just like you would normally:

```
{{#each}}
    {{this}} <!-- this refers to a tag -->
{{/each}}
```

If you provide a model to `{{render}}` then `{[render}}` will instantiate a new instance of the controller rather than use a singleton so you won't need to specify that the PopularPostsController is not a singleton.

**Update:**

Here's some information on how you could build a widget using a self contained component based on your comments.

Components are nice because you could set a bunch of parameters on your custom component like this:

```
{{my-component tag=tag sortOrder=sortOrder sortColumn=sortColumn}}
```

(note that component names are dasherized instead of camelCase)

In the component itself you could grab the data based on the passed in parameters like this:

```
App.MyComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    getData: function(){
       var tag = this.get('tag');
       var sortOrder = this.get('sortOrder');
       var sortColumn = this.get('sortColumn');
       //make your ajax call here to retrieve data           
       this.set('posts', dataFromAjax);
    }.on("init")
});
```

Instead of using the `on` event style you can just override init as well like this:

```
App.MyComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    init: function(){
       this._super(); //don't forget to call the parent init if you use this method 
       var tag = this.get('tag');
       var sortOrder = this.get('sortOrder');
       var sortColumn = this.get('sortColumn');
       //make your ajax call here to retrieve data           
       this.set('posts', dataFromAjax);
    }
});
```

The parameters are bound when using a component (not possible with `{{render}}`) so you can observe for changes on `sortOrder` and `sortColumn` to change the sort order of posts using `Ember.computed.sort`:

```
App.MyComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    getData: function(){
       var tag = this.get('tag');
       var sortOrder = this.get('sortOrder');
       var sortColumn = this.get('sortColumn');
       //make your ajax call here to retrieve data
       this.set('posts', dataFromAjax);
    }.on("init"),
    sortProperties: function(){
        return [this.get('sortColumn') + ':' + this.get('sortOrder')];
    }.property('sortColumn', 'sortOrder'),
    sortedPosts: Ember.computed.sort('posts', 'sortProperties'),
});
```

This very informative blog post has more info on using Ember.Computed.sort:

> http://balinterdi.com/2014/03/05/sorting-arrays-in-ember-dot-js-by-various-criteria.html

As usual the ember guide is actually very good and I would recommend looking it over real quick:

> http://emberjs.com/guides/components/

Comment: Can I pass tags like you've showed and then use these tags in a query in controller to fetch the real model, i.e. posts?

Comment: When you're on the page for a tag does that page have a route?  For example `/tag/1`.  If so, then I would probably fetch the tag data from the route itself.

Comment: It depends. This widget can be rendered in different templates, e.g. those rendered by route `/videos` or `/videos/:tag`. I'm looking for a way to create a widget/component that loads its own model data, but one can pass some additional data to use as a filter in the query (e.g. tag name, limit, order etc.), so that it can be used in any template without having to modify its parent controller.

Comment: I think a component is probably the way to go.  I updated the answer to provide some information on how you could do what you need with a component.  Feel free to keep asking questions if that doesn't get you heading in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try it out. I thought that fetching data in a component is a bad idea (it's kind of a view after all), but it should work.